# how to call block method from magento 1 template

Tags: php, xml, magento, templates

I'm new to magento and always have issues.

For now, I managed to add subscribe popup message and want to add a child block to my main block.

Code:(my custom module is `My_Module`)

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter_popup" as="newsletter_popup" template="popup/subscribe.phtml">
        <block type="Module/popup_newsletter" name="newsletter11" />
    </block>
</reference name="before_body_end">
```

and in `subscribe.phtml` I try the following:

```
var_dump($this->getChildHtml('newsletter11'))
```

but the result is:

> string(0)""

I tried to load the block from template in this way also:

```
var_dump($this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/popup_newsletter'));
```

but the result is `boolean(false).`

what I want to do is call a method from child block (`Newsletter.php`) and this out put some text, this block for now has these two methods:

```
puplic function test(){
    return 'this is test';
}

public function _toHtml()
{
    return test();
}
```

I can't see were is my mistake.

Can any one help me thankfully, I don't know if you need more code to post. Just let me know if you need

Thanks in advance.

**update:**
config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </my_module>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Helper</class>
            </my_module>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Block</class>
            </my_module>
        </blocks>
    </global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <My_Module>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>My_Module</module>
                <frontName>my</frontName>
            </args>
        </My_Module>
    </routers>
    </frontend>
```

Comment: you need call Module/popup_newsletter block function test() in phtml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create object for block in template (phmtl) file. Try the following code

```
$customBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('block_name'); // You can use newsletter11 in that block_name
```

To call block function

```
echo $customBlock->test();
```

Comment: thank you for you response.. I tried this:
var_dump($this->getLayout()->getBlock('module/popup_newsletter'));
but the result is bool(false) .. I don't now why

Comment: you want to call one of the function in that block right?

Comment: My block is extending Mage_Core_Block_Abstract is that correct??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58343/discussion-between-meenakshi-sundaram-r-and-allgood).

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('cms/block')
            ->setBlockId('seo-homepage')
            ->toHtml();
?>
```

Where seo-homepage  is your static block identifier

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

**$customBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('block-class-name');**

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add block

$this->getLayout()->createBlock('route/path to the file')

Comment: did't get you.
can you give me example or apply it on code I posted